# Cannot get WinForms Drag&Drop to work when launching in a Citrix Application

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, citrix

We have a C# WinForms application and one control is using the DragDrop to collect files that is dropped onto it.
Recently, for infrastructural reasons, it was decided to move the application into Citrix and run it as a Citrix Application.
As far as we can see, everything works as expected part from the drop functionality.

The DragDrop has worked without any problem when running the desktop application outside Citrix. It also works if it is started from a Citrix Desktop. But when hosting it as a Citrix Application, No event is fired; not the DragDrop and not the DragEnter. The mouse marker just have the "denied" glyph, as if the AllowDrop would be false.

We have seen that some applications works as a Citrix Application (e.g. a standard Windows Explorer or Outlook), some behaved strange (as Adobe) and some did not work at all (as foxit reader).

Edit: This is a distillation of the code used when testing the problem.

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AllowDrop = true;
            DragEnter += Form1_DragEnter;
            DragDrop += Form1_DragDrop;
        }

        private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        }

        private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var formats = e?.Data?.GetFormats() ?? new[] { "<Null>" };
            var text = $"Formats: {string.Join(", ", formats)}";

            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
```

Edit2: The Citrix guys in our company have now tweaked the Citrix environment so we actually get the events but unfortunately not the FileDrop format that I used to work with. We are now only getting the FileContents format (with a null result when getting from that format) and FileGroupDescriptorW (with only the file name present, and not the path).
We are still working with Citrix on the matter, and I will post a result in the end.

Edit3: We rebuilt the solution, and went for something else then Drag&Drop over Citrix, and as I no longer am a part of that organization, I can no longer follow up on the result, but there was a tip in a reply below, for all of you who run into the same problem. I have not tested that tip though.

Comment: This is still very much a problem for us, but I guess (by the silence), that too few are using WinForms in Citrix. I can also see that only 36 persons have been viewing this question, so it does not look like it attracts any attention at all, really.

Comment: It's not clear what type of control you're attempting to use or what kind of files your attempting to drop onto it. You may consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. If applicable, adding images to your post may also be beneficial (perhaps an animated gif).

Comment: @user9938: Thanks for your reply. Yes. Maybe I should write a new application so others can test it. Our current application is very large, and requires internal resources to run, so it is not really possible to scale that down. But it is a normal WinForms Form and the files drag and dropped are any file. We use the file information to store the data internally. When it comes to Citrix, I am no expert, so I cannot tell you exact how that is setup.

Comment: Sorry that I have not provided a test application but we have tested more and working together with Citrix, we have come to the fact that we receive the events. I will however present the findings when we are done (for those who want to end up in the same problem)

Comment: [Top google hit](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX289473) seems very relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, that was the article that set the Citrix guys in our company on the path what could be done. At first, they could not work it out, but with the help from Citrix, they tweaked the environment so we actually got the events within our application. The problem right now is that we only get the FileContents and FileGroupDesriptorW formats. Getting the data from the first only gets null and the latter will only give me the filename and not the path. The Citrix team is currently looking into that. The format I worked with before is the FileDrop one.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same Problem with our WinForms Citrix application where drag and drop didn't work. In the desktop application it worked fine.

There seems to be a solution in the newer versions of Citrix, where you should be able to configure drag and drop behaviour: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX289473/drag-and-then-drop-files-between-a-citrix-session-and-a-local-endpoint

An alternativ way would be to drag and drop files from other Citrix applications to your Citrix application. In our case the user drags files from Outlook to our application. As soon as the user does this from the Citrix Outlook or for example from the Citrix Windows Explorer it works.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I did not update here at the forum, but we went for another solution instead, and currently, I am no longer in that project...